# Fabricjs canvas objects iterarion

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I got some problems with code below :

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.selection = false;
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('./svg/1.svg',
    function (objects) {
        canvas.add.apply(canvas, objects);
        canvas.renderAll();
    }); -- this part is working
obj = canvas.getObjects();
obj.forEach(function (item, i) {
    console.log('plz work');
    item.setColor('red');
    item.set('selectable', false);
    canvas.renderAll();
}); - this isn't working
```

When i write this code in js file it's not working, but when i run it in browser console it works perfectly. What's wrong with it?

Comment: are you trying to set all svg objects color to red?

Comment: @ℊααnd it's just a demo. Main thing that this isn't working properly when i just open page with this.

Comment: @ℊααnd color isn't changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, **`obj`** array has no objects in it (meaning it­*'s* empty), when you are iterating over it, as there isn't any other objects on the canvas, and since `loadSVGFromURL` method is asynchronous, you can't really get hold of the SVG objects until it­*'s* properly loaded and added to the canvas.

To resolve this, simply do the iteration inside the callback function of **`loadSVGFromURL`**.

Here is the working code :

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.selection = false;
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('https://istack.000webhostapp.com/1tf.svg', function(objects) {
   canvas.add.apply(canvas, objects);
   canvas.renderAll();

   //do the iteration here
   obj = canvas.getObjects();
   obj.forEach(function(item, i) {
      console.log('plz work');
      item.setColor('red');
      item.set('selectable', false);
      canvas.renderAll();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.16/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```